# Generating interpolated values using an animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, uikit-dynamics

I would like to (ab-)use Core Animation or even UIDynamics to generate animated values (floats) that I could use to control other parameters.

E.g. Having an animation with an ease in, I would like to control a color with an 'eased' value.

Answer (score 3):

Core Animation can certainly do this for you. You need to create a `CALayer` subclass that has a new property you'd like to animate:

```
class CustomLayer: CALayer {

    @NSManaged var colorPercentage: Float

    override required init(layer: AnyObject) {
        super.init(layer: layer)

        if let layer = layer as? CustomLayer {
            colorPercentage = layer.colorPercentage
        } else {
            colorPercentage = 0.0
        }
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        var needsDisplay = super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)

        if key == "colorPercentage" {
            needsDisplay = true
        }

        return needsDisplay
    }

    override func action(forKey key: String) -> CAAction? {
        var action = super.action(forKey: key)

        if key == "colorPercentage" {
            action = super.action(forKey: "opacity")     // Create reference action from an existing CALayer key

            if let action = action as? CABasicAnimation {
                action.keyPath = key
                action.fromValue = value(forKeyPath: key)
            }
        }

        return action
    }

    override func display() {
        guard let presentationLayer = presentation() else { return }

        print("Current 'colorPercentage' value: \(presentationLayer.colorPercentage)")
        // Called for every frame of an animation involving "colorPercentage"
    }
}
```

(In Swift, `@NSManaged` is a hack currently necessary for Core Animation to treat `colorPercentage` as an Objective-C `@dynamic` property.)

Following this pattern, you can create a custom layer that contains your own animatable properties. `display()` will be called for every frame of the animation on the main thread, so you can respond to value changes over time however you'd like:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colorPercentage")
animation.duration = 1.0
animation.fromValue = customLayer.colorPercentage

customLayer.colorPercentage = 1.0
customLayer.add(animation, forKey: "colorPercentageAnimation")
```

As a bonus, `action(forKey:)` can be used to create an action from a "reference animation" that Core Animation knows about and configures it to work with your custom property. With this, it's possible to invoke `CALayer` animations inside UIKit-style animation closures, which are much more convenient to use:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    customLayer.colorPercentage = 1.0            
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to use [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/). See this [post](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/02/23/ios-animating-with-cadisplaylink.html). Changes of an animation are not observable by KVO.

Comment: This would be most useful for **monitoring** the presentation value of an existing animatable property, like the opacity of some view, to respond to visual changes to that value. But for custom properties, it's cleaner to make a `CALayer` subclass that defines such custom properties as animatable.